# Need help modifying a form JS script to add a success message

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I need help modifying this script to add a success message that would show in a div on the page. If there is a way to hide the submit button as well after the form is submitted, that would be helpful in preventing folks from spamming the submit button over and over again.

```
$().ready(function() {
    // validate board form choices and submit
    $("#custom_board_form").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            lastname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
        },
        messages: {
            firstname: {
                required: "Please enter a name",
                minlength: "Your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            lastname: {
                required: "Please enter a name",
                minlength: "Your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
                email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        },

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using jQuery Validation plugin. Add this to your configuration object:

```
validate({
  rules: ...
  messages: ...
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('#submitButton').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#successMessage').text('Success message!');
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

(replacing your own elements for the submit button ID and the ID of an empty element that will receive the success message).

EDIT: Oops, wrong hook.

Comment: Yes I am using jQuery Validation plugin....thanks for the quick reply. I will test this in a bit...

Comment: This is for some reason validating the form as soon as the rules are met for the email and name. As soon as any of the rules are met, the success message is displayed and the submit button greyed out before the form is even submitted. Any ideas?

Comment: Right on! Thanks! That works but introduces a new issue...where after submit form and success message displays, the whole page then goes white and the link in the address bar displays my php page...?

Comment: That's the normal consequence of submitting a form if your receiving PHP does not output anything; I can't see it having anything to do with validation, and I believe same would happen if you did not use validation at all. What do you want to happen?

Comment: I figured it had something to do with that. I think I would just want the success message to display and the user stay on the same page.

Comment: In that case, you need to use AJAX. Replace `form.submit()` with an appropriate invocation of `$.ajax`.

Comment: This is what I ended up with....it works, just wanted to see if you saw any issues with it. <br />

`submitHandler: function(form) {
   $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#successMessage').text('Success message!');

   $.post('http://www.hannahbboards.com/code/build a board/form/sendcustomorder.php', 

   $('form#custom_board_form').serialize() , 

   function(data){

    alert(data.msg);

   }, "json");`